# ListViewWebPart programmatically set the List/Path

Tags: custom, list-view-web-part

The ListView Webpart is a component created to show a list inside a page... It's very usefull and easy to use... The way to create a ListViewWebPart and set a list is very simple:

```
        myListView = new Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart();
        myListView.Visible = true;
        myListView.EnableViewState = true;
        SPList list = oWebSite.Lists[listName];
        myListView.ListName = list.ID.ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant();
        myListView.TitleUrl = list.DefaultViewUrl;
        myListView.WebId = list.ParentWeb.ID;
        myListView.ListId = (System.Guid)list.ID;
        myListView.ViewGuid = list.DefaultView.ID.ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant();
        Controls.Add(myListView);
```

When i click on a folder inside the webpart it redirect me to an url like this:

http://sp2010dev/SitePages/Home.aspx?RootFolder=%2fdocs%2fiuihuoho&FolderCTID=&View=%7b9EE11E87%2dEF54%2d48B9%2dB386%2d24DFB4B36C42%7d

In wich Sharepoint sets the folder to access... Is it possible to set that folder programmatically without using the RootFolder parameter? And a way to avoid the "reading" of the query string if i want to force the list to my orders?

Anybody knows a way? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I did this before using this example:

http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2010/11/displaying-files-from-a-specific-folder-using-spdatasource/

I hope that helps.